# DateTime string format last digit of year

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I wonder if there is a better way to get the last digit of a year from a datatime object

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
string year1 = date.ToString("y"); //NOT OK return Month year (eg March 2012)
char year2 = date.ToString("yy")[1]; //OK return last digit of the year (eg 2)
char year3 = date.ToString("yy").Last(); //OK same as above using linq
```

Anyone know if an already predifine format exist for retreiving the last digit of the year?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do that with simple Modulo math:

```
int digit = date.Year % 10;
```

Comment: if you take mod 10 then it will return 5 from 2005

Comment: Nice. Although you should use modulo 10 rather than modulo 100.

Comment: Nice!  I almost forgot about mod.

Comment: It was 10 originally; someone edited and changed it to 100 :-( Anyway, I corrected it back to 10.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to get the last digit of the year.

---

There is a custom format string "y", but that will still return two digits, only not zero padded. I.e. 2009 will be formatted as "9", but 2010 will be formatted as "10".

You can use an empty string literal to make "y" be the custom format string instead of the standard format string:

```
date.ToString("''y");
```

This will return the two last digits, for example "12", rather than the standard format "March 2012".

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
int digit = d.Year % 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(3);
```